# How do I get the div background to change when I mouse over a link - using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a background image on a div and I would like to change its position from center bottom to center top when I mouse over the link which is in the div.

I don't speak jQuery very well, I am kind of like the American in France, knowing little more than parlez vous, but here goes.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="video-link">
 <a href="#">Watch the Pack It Videos Now.</a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.video-link { 
        width: 610px;
        height: 68px;
        background: url(../_images/btn_horz-video.png) no-repeat center bottom;
        margin: 10px 0 10px 50px; 
        }

.video-link a { 
        color: #000; 
        text-decoration: none; 
        border: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        display: block;
        padding: 25px 0 0 90px; font-weight: bold; }
```

And last but not least, here is the jQuery:

```
$(".video-link a").hover(function() {
  $(this).closest(".div").css({ 'background-position': 'top center' });
  }, function() {
  $(this).closest(".div").css({ 'background-position': 'bottom center' });
});
```

Here is [the page](http://www.rouviere.com/_move/about.html) - It is the Watch the Pack It Videos Now image about midway down the page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your [`.closest(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), instead of `".div"` you just need `"div"`, like this:

```
$(".video-link a").hover(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").css({ 'background-position': 'top center' });
}, function() {
  $(this).closest("div").css({ 'background-position': 'bottom center' });
});
```

`.div` is a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) looking for a `class="div"` element, whereas `div` is an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), looking for `<div>`.

Comment: Hi Nick, you helped me on something very similar about three months ago. Well done! thanks.

Comment: Good catch! I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 4):

I would just change it to this:

```
$(".video-link").hover(
    function()
    {
        $(this).css({ 'background-position': 'top center' });
    },
    function()
    {
        $(this).css({ 'background-position': 'bottom center' });
    });
```

I tested it on your site and it worked.

EDIT: What I did was remove the a and just applied the hover to the div. Then I took out the closest method call and just applied the css change to this since it now applies to the div. Obviously this wouldn't work if other places are using this css but I didn't see any.

Comment: While this works, I would make 2 comments here...the first is that this isn't genuine anymore, you're giving a hover state for an area that if clicked, might no do anything (outside the link, still on the div)...the second, I would do this purely in CSS if doing the hover on the div, no reason for JS/jQuery in that case :)

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery Mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/).

Comment: Why do you recommend `mouseover` instead of `hover`? Care to elaborate?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like hover may be better as mouseover won't work if display:none is set.